# Which open source javascript projects to look at to learn how to write large programs in the language

Tags: javascript, architecture

I have quite a lot of experience in large scale development in Java. However, I want to learn how to do so in JavaScript. Could anybody point me some great large (> 20KLOC, or even > 100KLOC) open source projects in JavaScript which I can learn from.

Particularly I want to learn:

- How to structures JS projects
- How to test them
- How to refactor them

P.S. I read several good JS books including JS Good Parts, but neither of them satisfied my needs. Most of them are just about small (< 20k lines of code). I also aware of Closure compiler, but find its approach unsatisfactory. For me, it's similar to translating code from Java to JavaScript manually with some annotations and using checker to make sure the types are correct. I'd rather use GWT (which I currently do).

Comment: AngularJS, EmberJS, JQuery, Dojo, Mootools it's up to you. The best thing is to pick a framework or popular library.

Comment: @amchang87 All the libraries which you mentioned are < 10KLOC

Comment: I don't see how lines of code makes any difference. A smaller code base can be well structured and tested and will scale up well.

Comment: @Juhana Lines of code actually make difference but not so directly. Of course architecture, can reduce amount of code, but not so dramatically. If you want to create a really large project, for example, something in the spirit of google docs, you won't be able to fit in 10KLOC.

Comment: @Juhana Could you please explain why you closed it? 

I understand that in the world of some of you, jquery is an obvious large scale library, but there are other people who create much more complex software, and you aren't have any expertise judging their questions. And if you don't have expertise, it's better to vote on the question which are about areas which you are expert at.

Comment: *"...this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion."* See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: @Juhana Why will it solicit polling? I just asked for examples.

Comment: That's what polling means.